# Measures on $\mathbb{R}$ which are invariant under addition and multiplication

Tags: real-analysis

Is there a finite measure on $\mathbb{R}$ which is invariant both under addition and multiplication?

i.e., is there a finite measure $\mu$ s.t.  $\mu(rA)=\mu(A)$ and $\mu(r+A)=\mu(A)$ for all $r\in \mathbb{R}$ and measurable $A\subset \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Please specify what you mean by addition and multiplication.

Comment: The zero measure will do.

Comment: Depends on your sigma-algebra. In the Borel-sigma-algebra there is only the zero measure with those properties. But if you take for example $\{ \emptyset, \mathbb{R} \}$ as your sigma algebra, then you have some more.